# React-js: briefly wrong div loaded in conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, metamask

The following script allows the react-app to connect to Metamask, then show the homepage; moreover, if the user is already connected

> walletAddress.length>0

, we want to show directly the homepage. (I simplified the code to make it clearer)

```
function App() {
  const [walletAddress, setWallet] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    rememberWallet();
    addWalletListener();
  }, []);

  const connectWalletPressed = async () => {
    const obj = await getCurrentWalletConnected('eth_requestAccounts')
    setWallet(obj.address);
};

async function rememberWallet(){
    const obj = await getCurrentWalletConnected('eth_accounts')
    setWallet(obj.address)
}


function addWalletListener() {
    window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            setWallet(accounts[0]);
        } else {
            setWallet("");
        }
    });
}
  console.log(walletAddress)
  return (
    walletAddress.length>0 ?
    <div>HOME PAGE</div>:
    <div><button id="walletButton" onClick={connectWalletPressed}>PRESS TO CONNECT METAMASK</button> </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The point is: when the user is already connected, the second  is rendered for a moment.

I really appreciate any suggestionùthanks

Comment: do you know if user is already connect prior to calling the  `app` component?  Can you initialize `const [walletAddress, setWallet] = useState(existingUser);` with an `existingUser` value.

Comment: You could also create another state value called `loading` and set it to false.  Then if loading, show `HOME PAGE` or whatever.  Then once `loading` is completed show the value based on `walletAddress`.

Comment: Thank you @Hozeis. Unfortunately, I think I can't initialitize `const [walletAddress, setWallet]`. I may use `loading` to show a loading page while browser assesses `walletAddress.length>0 ?`, however I would like to know a way to solve it without adding a new page

Comment: You don't have to show a new page, you can always show the home page, but then the same effect would happen for users not logged in.  Ur only other option that I can think of is just to delay the render and display a blank screen until we load, but that isn't that great either {loading ? null : page}

Comment: Yeah I go for the delay, 50 ms seems to work well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hozeis, We found a workaround using a time-out of 50 ms showing a blank page.

```
function App() {
    const [walletAddress, setWallet] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
  
    useEffect(() => {
      rememberWallet();
      addWalletListener();
      setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 50); //time-out required to assess myContext.walletAddress.length>0 ?
    }, []);
  
    const connectWalletPressed = async () => {
      const obj = await getCurrentWalletConnected('eth_requestAccounts')
      setWallet(obj.address);
  };
  
  async function rememberWallet(){
      const obj = await getCurrentWalletConnected('eth_accounts')
      setWallet(obj.address)
  }
  
  
  function addWalletListener() {
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
          if (accounts.length > 0) {
              setWallet(accounts[0]);
          } else {
              setWallet("");
          }
      });
  }
  if (loading) {
    return null
}

    return (
      walletAddress.length>0 ?
      <div>HOME PAGE</div>:
      <div><button id="walletButton" onClick={connectWalletPressed}>PRESS TO CONNECT METAMASK</button> </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```